# How to load and validate a form using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

let's say I have 2 pages :
index.html with this code :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">

<head>
    <title>test formulaire</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="formulaire">
    </div>
    <!-- /#formulaire -->
    <a href="javascript:montreformulaire();">Montre le formulaire</a>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/monscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have an other page that containts my form :

```
<form name="monformulaire" id="monformulaire" role="monformulaire">
<input type="text" name="montexte" id="montexte" value="" />
<button id="bouton" type="submit">Let's go man !</button>
</form>
```

I have a Jquery.js and a personnal script like this :

```
function montreformulaire() {
    alert('ok charge formulaire');
    $.get( "monformulaire.html", function( data ) {
    var formData = $.parseHTML (data );
        $( "#formulaire" ).html( formData );
    });
    $('monformulaire').submit(function(event) {
            alert('formulaire envoyé !');
            event.preventDefault();
            /*
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'ajoute.php',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data) {
                    alert($('form').serialize());
                    //showMsg(data);
                    showSupportPage(id);

                },
                cache: false
            });
            */
    });
    $( "#montexte" ).val( 'toto' );
}
```

my problem is that when the form is submit I want to use a jquery submit function but it doesn't work.

I don't see why and how I could fix that.

Any idea is welcome :-)

Thanks,

Alex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very classic and common question. You make an ajax call to an element, but you do element.click(...) before it is fetched, thus before it actually exists.

Place the `$('#monformulaire').submit(function` (with a #, that you forgot) inside the ajax callback function, like this :

```
$.get( "monformulaire.html", function( data ) { // This is done FIRST
            var formData = $.parseHTML (data );
            $( "#formulaire" ).html( formData ); // this is done THIRD, #monformulaire now exists
            $('#monformulaire').submit(function(event) {........}) // this is done FOURTH, accessing the element!
});

$('#monformulaire').submit(function(event) {........}) // This is done SECOND and won't do anything because #monformulaire doesn't exist yet
```

Welcome to the world of async languages :)

Answer (score 2):

Because you missed a `#` while passing the `id` on `submit` handler

```
$('#monformulaire').submit(function(event) {

            // Your code here..
});
```

Other selector is

```
    $('[name=monformulaire]').submit({
                // Your code here..
    });
```

Choose whichever suits you.

Answer (score 0):

Your submit functions is not good. Do it like so:

```
$('[name=monformulaire]').submit();
```

or

```
$('[name=monformulaire]').submit(function(){
    //Do your thing here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `$('form[name="monformulaire"]').submit(...)`